# How to explicit a term from an equation in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I need to explicit the variable K, in function of P and T, from this equation.
[formula here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3gcY.png)
I've done all steps up until now but this has got me stuck. I've tried to use `solve` from sympy library but it doesn't work.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve
#define symbols
T, P, K = symbols('T P K')
eq = sp.Eq(1.08866210790363*K*(1 - 0.5*K)**0.5/(0.666666666666667 - K)**1.5, 1.99036339653399e+441*P*sp.exp((0.724859000422363*P + 461.638532977748*P/T - 101419.64390802)/T)/T**344.113039591901)

solv=sp.solve(eq, K)
```

Sorry in advance if i omitted something, i'm new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we simplify your equation slightly we can divide the constant from the lhs over to the right and then just make the expression on the right be a symbol z since it doesn't depend on K. We can also replace floats with rationals which is particular important if there are floats in the exponents. That looks like this:

```
In [44]: eq = S('Eq(1.08866210790363*K*(1 - 0.5*K)**0.5/(0.666666666666667 - K)**1.5, 1.9903633965339
    ...: 9e+441*P*exp((0.724859000422363*P + 461.638532977748*P/T - 101419.64390802)/T)/T**344.113039
    ...: 591901)')

In [45]: eq
Out[45]: 
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
                                          -1.5            0.5                            -344.11303
1.08866210790363⋅K⋅(0.666666666666667 - K)    ⋅(1 - 0.5⋅K)    = 1.99036339653399e+441⋅P⋅T          

                               461.638532977748⋅P                  
         0.724859000422363⋅P + ────────────────── - 101419.64390802
                                       T                           
         ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
9591901                              T                             
       ⋅ℯ                                                          

In [46]: eq = Eq(Mul(*nsimplify(eq.lhs).args[1:]), z)

In [47]: eq
Out[47]: 
      _______    
     ╱     K     
K⋅  ╱  1 - ─     
  ╲╱       2     
───────────── = z
          3/2    
 (2/3 - K)
```

Now we can solve this easily with `check=False` and get three different solutions:

```
In [48]: sol = solve(eq, K, check=False)

In [49]: len(sol)
Out[49]: 3
```

Here's the first solution:

```
In [53]: sol[0]
Out[53]: 
                                                                                                                             ________________________________________________________________________________________________    
                                                                                                                            ╱                                  _________________________________________________________         
                                                                                                                           ╱                                  ╱                     3                                 2          
                                                                                                                          ╱                                  ╱      ⎛       2      ⎞    ⎛         2           2      ⎞           
                                                                                                                         ╱                                  ╱       ⎜   24⋅z       ⎟    ⎜    432⋅z       144⋅z       ⎟           
                                                                                                                        ╱                                  ╱    - 4⋅⎜- ──────── + 4⎟  + ⎜- ────────── + ──────── - 16⎟           
                                                         2                                                             ╱               2          2       ╱         ⎜     2        ⎟    ⎜      2           2         ⎟           
                                                     24⋅z                                                             ╱           216⋅z       72⋅z      ╲╱          ⎝  6⋅z  - 3    ⎠    ⎝  54⋅z  - 27   6⋅z  - 3     ⎠           
                                                  - ──────── + 4                                                     ╱        - ────────── + ──────── + ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - 8     
                                                       2                                                          3 ╱               2           2                                      2                                         
                                                    6⋅z  - 3                                                      ╲╱            54⋅z  - 27   6⋅z  - 3                                                                           2
- ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ─
               ________________________________________________________________________________________________                                                        3                                                        3
              ╱                                  _________________________________________________________                                                                                                                       
             ╱                                  ╱                     3                                 2                                                                                                                        
            ╱                                  ╱      ⎛       2      ⎞    ⎛         2           2      ⎞                                                                                                                         
           ╱                                  ╱       ⎜   24⋅z       ⎟    ⎜    432⋅z       144⋅z       ⎟                                                                                                                         
          ╱                                  ╱    - 4⋅⎜- ──────── + 4⎟  + ⎜- ────────── + ──────── - 16⎟                                                                                                                         
         ╱               2          2       ╱         ⎜     2        ⎟    ⎜      2           2         ⎟                                                                                                                         
        ╱           216⋅z       72⋅z      ╲╱          ⎝  6⋅z  - 3    ⎠    ⎝  54⋅z  - 27   6⋅z  - 3     ⎠                                                                                                                         
  3⋅   ╱        - ────────── + ──────── + ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - 8                                                                                                                   
    3 ╱               2           2                                      2                                                                                                                                                       
    ╲╱            54⋅z  - 27   6⋅z  - 3
```

Because we disabled checking the solutions might not all be valid but you can verify for yourself which is correct.

Finally you can substitute in for `z` to these solutions but you will get some big and complicated expressions back so I won't show them here.

Comment: I was stuck on this for a good while...thank you very much for clearing this up for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `sympy` enough, so here's just to point out the problem: the value of `1.99036339653399e+441` is so large that double precision floating-point numbers cannot represent it:

```
>>> 1.99036339653399e+441
inf
```

We replace it with Python's decimal:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1.99036339653399e+441')
Decimal('1.99036339653399E+441')
```

In this way, the `solve` function can run, but due to the complexity of the equation, the program needs to consume a lot of memory (9GiB+!) and time, and it may not even be able to solve successfully.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up, i''l be more careful next time!